# Using jq to conditionally flatten recursive json

Tags: recursion, jq

The simplest version of the input document I could come up with is

```
{
    "references": [
        {
            "version": 5,
            "id": "id1",
            "objType": "A"
        },
        {
            "version": 4,
            "id": "id2",
            "objType": "B",
            "referencing": []
        },
        {
            "version": 4,
            "id": "id3",
            "objType": "B",
            "referencing": [
                {
                    "version": 2,
                    "id": "id4",
                    "objType": "A"
                },
                {
                    "version": 3,
                    "id": "id5",
                    "objType": "B",
                    "referencing": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Objects of type A have no referencing objects.

Objects of type B can be referenced by either type of object.

There are two outputs I need from this json:

Output #1 is the version info for objects of type A with the `id` value as a key with the value of `version`. `A` objects can be at the top level or at some arbitrary depth in the `referencing` arrays.

```
{
    "references": {
        "id1": {"version": 5},
        "id4": {"version": 2}
    }
}
```

The 2nd output is similar: the version info for objects of type B. The can be a chain of type `B` objects referencing other type `B` objects.

```
{
    "references": {
        "id2": {"version": 4},
        "id3": {"version": 4},
        "id5": {"version": 3}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [recursive decsent](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#RecursiveDescent:..) operator and [from_entries](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries). You don't need to follow the "references" (at least not to produce the expected output in your question)

```json
{
    dependencies: [.. | select(.objType=="A")? | { key: .id, value: {version} }] | from_entries
},
{
    dependencies: [.. | select(.objType=="B")? | { key: .id, value: {version} }] | from_entries
}
```

Output:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "id1": {
      "version": 5
    },
    "id4": {
      "version": 2
    }
  }
}
{
  "dependencies": {
    "id2": {
      "version": 4
    },
    "id3": {
      "version": 4
    },
    "id5": {
      "version": 3
    }
  }
}
```

It's also possible to merge ([add](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#add)) objects instead of constructing them from their entries, which makes the code minimally shorter:

```
{
    dependencies: [.. | select(.objType=="A")? | { (.id): {version} }] | add
}
```

Comment: Thanks @knittl. Both options work fine. I'd tried both recursive descent and `recurse()` but didn't get the invocation quite right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recurse` to traverse the document, `INDEX` to create an object with IDs as keys, `map_values` to format their values using `select` to reduce according to your criteria.

```bash
jq --arg type A '
  .references |= (
    INDEX(.[] | recurse(.referencing[]?); .id)
    | map_values(select(.objType == $type) | {version})
  )
'
```

```json
{
  "references": {
    "id1": {
      "version": 5
    },
    "id4": {
      "version": 2
    }
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1qM837mpov8)

This works for both questions, provide `A` or `B` to `--arg type`.

Note that this is using the error suppression operator `?` when recursing down. If you want to restrict the traversal explicitly to `.objType == "B"`, just prepend it in a `select` expression, i.e. replace `recurse(.referencing[]?)` with `recurse(select(.objType == "B") | .referencing[])`. [Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/t512claPIjW)

Comment: Thanks (again). Would there be much difference between your approach and what @knittl suggested above? My source documents are not large so both approaches seem similar in terms of performance.

Comment: @GBC The most noteable difference between `recurse(f)` and `..` is that with the former you can explicitly define the recursion path beforehand, whereas with the latter you have to cut off unwanted branches as they come in. Both will accomplish the same task, but it may boil down to how ramified your overall structure is. For instance, if only objects of type B had descendants, a catch-all is the simpler approach. If, however, objects of type A also had descendants but you wouldn't consider them in this recursion, it'd be more straightforward to explicitly design it that way.